# How to handle painting with movement of cabinet door panel movement?

Tags: painting, cabinets

I am building new kitchen cabinet boxes with face frames.  It is a no-brainer to pay for shaker style doors to be built and shipped to me, but I have some questions about how the paint will behave:

- With the expansion and contraction of the floating panels, won't the unfinished panel inside the rails show unless they are primed/painted before assembly and shipping?
- Would a clear coat make the paint more durable or is this more a function of the primer/paint combination?

Comment: Are you sure the panels won't be glued? Are you willing to glue them? I'm not sure I'd want to deal with the rattling noise with loose panels.

Comment: @isherwood if they're solid wood, the panels will float. That's why doors are made with panels - to allow for the expansion. They don't rattle unless they're _poorly_ made.

Comment: No, they're made with panels because it would be extremely difficult to carve them from a single board (and the grain would look odd). I've installed and used raised-panel doors for decades, and they don't float freely. I'm in the middle of oak central here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately durability is largely impacted by level of prep and primer. This is for one main reason.. adhesion.

A great top coat is nothing without a good key on the surface and also good primer.

All that said, paints vary on how they handle movement. In a coloured top coat, a high acryllic content paint will help with movement.

Another option is a polyurethane varnish ontop. The stuff is super durable.